# UIPopovercontroller in UISplitViewController

Tags: objective-c, uisplitviewcontroller, uipopovercontroller

My detailviewcontroller is called myDetailVC , with tableVC which is just a table on the side of myDetailVC.

in myDetailVC, I have a button that is supposed to show a popoverviewcontroller. However, it crashes when I press it.

in my .h file:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIPopoverController *masterPopOverController;
```

and .m:

```
- (IBAction)goToPDF:(id)sender
{


        viewPDFViewController *MPPWV =[[viewPDFViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];

        self.masterPopOverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:MPPWV];

        [self.masterPopOverController presentPopoverFromRect:[sender frame] inView:[sender superview] permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
        [self.masterPopOverController setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(100, 100) animated:NO];


    }
```

Everything is connected fine in my xib, since I tested it by making it push to a viewcontroller instead of a popover. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Can you push to the `viewPDFViewController` successfully?

Comment: @aaron yup i can push to vewPDFVC, that works fine, but then I found that i didn'tdo something right and it can't go back to the detailvc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it looks like you're loading it up with a view controller that doesn't have anything in it:

```
viewPDFViewController *MPPWV =[[viewPDFViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
```

Try specifying a Nib name, if you have one. It's possible that you don't have a NIB for that view controller. If that's the case you probably have a designated initializer `-init` method that you should be calling on it. Do that instead of calling `-initWithNibName:`

Second, it doesn't look like you're retaining the view controller you're loading into the pop over. It's possible that they require strong references. Try retaining it via property (or an ivar):

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) viewPDFViewController * MMPPWV;
```

Then when you access it do so via `self`:

```
self.MPPWV = [[viewPDFViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
```

Comment: i will try this and let you know what happens!

Comment: Just added another suggestion.

Comment: it works! thank you, i alos changed initWithContentViewController:self.MPPWV